# How to remove tbody data inside a modal

Tags: javascript, html-table, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to remove tbody data inside a modal when cancel button is clicked. My code works but it removes including the thead. can someone point out whats wrong with my code. Is it possible to remove only the tbody area of the table instead of removing the whole table content?

```js
 var size = document.getElementById('partnersize').value;
 counter = 0;
 //alert(size);
 for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  var branchname = document.getElementById('branchname['+i+']').value;
  var branchid = document.getElementById('branchid['+i+']').value;
  var balance = document.getElementById('balance['+i+']').value;
  var amount = document.getElementById('amount['+i+']').value;
  if(amount!="")
   {
   $('#confirmModal').find('.table').append('<tr><td id="branchname'+counter+'">'+branchname+'</td><td id="branchid'+counter+'">'+branchid+'</td><td id="balance'+counter+'">'+balance+'</td><td id="amount'+counter+'">'+amount+'</td></tr>');
   counter = counter + 1;
   }
 } 
 $('#confirmModal').modal('show');
  $('#closeBtn').click(function(){
 
  $('#confirmModal').find('.tbody').html("");
  
 
 });
```

```html
<table class="table" id="table"> <!-- table-bordered table-striped-->
      <thead>
        <tr>
         
          <th id="removetable">
            Branch Name
        
          </th>
          <th id="removetable">
            Branch Id
       
          </th>
          <th id="removetable">
           Balance
       
          </th>

          <th id="removetable">
            Amount
   
          </th>
          
          <!--  <th id="removetable">
            Status
       
          </th> -->
           
        
        </tr>
      </thead>
      
      <tbody id="tableBody">
          <div id="data" style="padding-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 47px; float: right; color:#FF0000;">
          
          </div>
      </tbody>
      
    </table>
```

Comment: You have duplicate IDs, which is invalid markup, and is the likely cause of your problem. Use classes instead. You also need to provide a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem for us to really be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for the input but the multiple IDs didnt affect what i was going for, thanks for noticing though i removed those IDs to prevent problems in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$("#TableIDHere tbody").empty();
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. it worked, thanks a lot!